# How does the LayoutInspector implementated of jetpack compose

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I want to get composable function’s name path. As the follow picture figured:
[image]

The Text Element]s function name path maybe: ComposetestTheme/Column/Text.

My question is how the compose implement the layout inspector, where is the codes.

Comment: Layout Inspector is a tool provided by Android Studio.